# VBA or formula to separate street names and suffixes in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to separate millions of street names from their suffixes ("Ave", "Dr", "St", etc.) in Excel. Sometimes streets do not have a suffix, so an empty cell is needed for those.

[image: Example result needed]

I tried using a formula at first, but ran into some issues:

Listed the suffixes with the highlighted example formula below and then using CONCAT in the last column to get them all in one column , but sometimes it also grabs directionals ("S", "N", "E", "W") after the suffix,
[image]

lists two suffixes with the same letters (e.g. "CI", "CIR"),
[image: two suffixes with same letters]

or grabs the street name if it includes the same letters as a suffix (see "ST" column).
[image: street names with same letters as a listed suffix]

I've also tried **Flash Fill**, but this yields worse results.

I came to the conclusion VBA would be most efficient because I will have to repeat this process for multiple datasets, but if there are other suggestions I am open.

I am very novice in VBA, but this is what I have so far and I'm not sure how to expand/continue it:

```
Sub getSuffix()

Dim i As Range



For Each i In Range("A1")
  Do
    If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, " AVE") > 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "AVE"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Else
        
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
        Exit For
    
        
        End If
    
    End If

Loop

Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want vba, or a formula?  If vba would you like it to be a Function that can be called like a formula from the sheet.  All are possible.

Comment: @ScottCraner I meant "formula" above, not "function"--fixed. VBA preferably (since I am trying to use it more). I couldn't think of a cell formula, so I'd be curious to see both if someone has the time.

Comment: you still do not ask a question in the "Question" above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It should be fast enough, using arrays, working only in memory and dropping the processing result at once:

```
Sub SplitBySuffix()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long
 Dim arr, arrStr, arrS, arrSuff, arrInt, boolFound As Boolean
 
 arrSuff = Split("AVE,PL,LN,ST,DR,WY", ",") 'put here all the necessary suffixes (Upper case)
                                            '"AVE" is different than ".AVE"...
 Set sh = ActiveSheet                       'use here your necessary sheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row of A:A

 arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).value   'put the range to be processed in an array
 ReDim arrStr(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'redim the street array
 ReDim arrS(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)   'redim the suffix array
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr) 'iterate between the array to be processed elements
    arrInt = Split(arr(i, 1), " ")      'split the array element by space (" ")
    'check if the last array element is a suffix:
    If Not IsError(Application.match(UCase(arrInt(UBound(arrInt))), arrSuff, 0)) Then
        arrS(i, 1) = arrInt(UBound(arrInt)): boolFound = True
    End If
    If boolFound Then 'if a suffix has been found:
        'eliminate the last array element_________________________
        arrInt(UBound(arrInt)) = arrInt(UBound(arrInt)) & "##$$@@"
        arrInt = Filter(arrInt, arrInt(UBound(arrInt)), False)
        '_________________________________________________________
        arrStr(i, 1) = Join(arrInt, " ") 'put in the street array the joined filter result
        boolFound = False          'reinitialize the boolean variable
    Else
        arrStr(i, 1) = arr(i, 1)   'put in the street array the element as it is
    End If
 Next i
 'drop the arrays content at once:
 sh.Range("B2").Resize(lastR - 1, 1) = arrStr
 sh.Range("C2").Resize(lastR - 1, 1) = arrS
End Sub
```

Comment: @rlo5029: Did you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it work as you need?

Comment: I just tested it. The code copied all of the original street names (column A) into column B. I listed all the necessary suffixes as you instructed:
`arrSuff = Split("AVE, AV, PL, LN, ST, DR, WY, WAY, CIR, CI, CT, BLVD, HWY, LOOP, LP, PKWY, PLZ, RD, SQ, SQUARE, TER, WALK, WK", ",") `

Comment: The array as you made it is wrong. No spaces aftter comma...

Comment: @rlo5029: Did you try the code creating `arrSuff` as it should be?

Comment: Yes, I did just now. Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @rlo5029: Glad I could help! If you like using the array as you initially built, you must split it on ", " instead of ","... Otherwise, each string has an extra space in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT the rules are as follows:

- You are looking for one of a set of suffixes (e.g. `Ave`, `Dr`, `St` ,`Cir`)
- that are preceded by a space, and
- are succeeded by either a space or the end of the string

I would suggest using regular expressions for this.

Add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...**) to the **Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5** library.

Then you can write code like the following:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim re As RegExp

Function GetSuffix(address As String) As String
If re Is Nothing Then
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    re.Pattern = " (Ave|Dr|St|Cir)( |$)"
End If
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Set matches = re.Execute(address)
If matches.Count > 0 Then GetSuffix = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
End Function
```

and use the function in a cell formula:

```
=GetSuffix(A4)
```

It will return the first matched suffix, excluding any subsequent characters.

You probably will want to add more suffixes, e.g.:

```vb
    re.Pattern = " (Ave|Dr|St|Cir|Wy|Ci|Pl|Aisle)( |$)"
```

---

Links:

- [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)
- [Introduction to Regular Expressions (Scripting)](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions//6wzad2b2%28v%3dvs.85%29)
- [Regular expression syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/1400241x(v=vs.85))
- API reference

  - [**RegExp** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions//yab2dx62(v=vs.85))
  - [**IgnoreCase**](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions//wy1d4bz3(v=vs.85)) and [**Pattern**](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions//f97kw5ka(v=vs.85)) properties
  - [**Execute** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions//yfy6y4h1(v=vs.85))
  - [**Matches** collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions//tx0sf6z1(v=vs.85))
  - [**Match** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions//h9k561zd(v=vs.85))
  - **SubMatches** property and [collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions//y27d2s18(v=vs.85))

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but this did not work for me. I added the Reference, pasted the first code in a module, then `=GetSuffix(A4)` in **[ThisWorkbook (Code)]**

Comment: I was using it incorrectly--it does work. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @rlo5029 What were you doing incorrectly?

Comment: I put `=GetSuffix(A4)` in the **ThisWorkbook** VBA window, not in the actual workbook as a formula. Dumb mistake on my part.